# вырезать из текста HTML сущности

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

у меня в исходном тексте (`Header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");`)
есть `textarea`, где вносится текст (допустимы русские и английские буквы, цифры, символы переноса строки и +). там могут быть и иероглифы и персидские фразы и всякие спецсимволы.

проблема: как убрать иероглифы, которые преобразуются в цифры.

я придумал так.
исходный текст:

```
sdfsdfsdf 早上好
```

```
$sInputText=htmlspecialchars($sInputText,1251);
```

преобразую иероглифы в сущности: `sdfsdfsdf &#26089;&#19978;&#22909;`

как убрать эти сущности?

пробовал регуляркой - почему-то не работает

```
$Text=preg_replace('/&(.+?);/','',$Text);
```

Comment: Функция preg_replace() принимает 3 параметра, а не 2 http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: вы правы- описался, поправил. не работает - вырезает из текста только &

Comment: хм, у меня удаляет все `&...;`, а не только `&`.

Comment: Используемое Вами регулярное выражение верно и должно делать ожидаемый результат. Проблема может быть с кодировкой текста. С какой кодировкой пхп работает по-умолчанию?

Comment: в начале файла указываю Header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251"); где-то еще надо указывать кодировку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Text=preg_replace('/&(.+?);/','',$Text);
```

замените на

```
$Text = preg_replace('/&(amp;)?(.+?);/', '', $Text);
```

**UPD**

```
$Text = preg_replace('/&(amp;)?#\d+;/', '', $Text);
```

Comment: @Prog2010, `null` не откуда взяться тут, если вы не подаете на входе `null`.

Comment: сейчас работает но немного неправильно. получается если в тексте встретится фраза с началом в & и концовкой в ; она удалится
пример "& 1ea22 dsf;"

Comment: @Prog2010, ну значит посмотрите в моем ответе более точную регулярку.

Comment: спасибо, все получилось.

Answer (score -1):

Вот такой код у меня работает

```
$text = "sdfsdfsdf &#26089;&#19978;&#22909;";

$res = trim(preg_replace("|([&#0-9;]+?)|",'', $text));

var_dump($res);
```

[Песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/86f3779c3bc1858ae04b658c7fb0eb75b6e68d0c)

Comment: Регулярное выражение ошибочно.

Comment: @ReinRaus, да что Вы? А у меня работает. Не знаете почему? Магия может быть?

Comment: Может быть потому что в Вашем тестовом тексте слишком мало данных? Попробуйте на тексте `12 обезьян & 1 я сидели на ветке; #ололо`

Comment: @ReinRaus, пример взят с шапки вопроса

Comment: код почти работает, но не до конца, вот что у меня получилось: "sdfsdfsdf ampampamp"

Comment: Попробуйте объяснить что означает Ваше регулярное выражение и Вы поймете, почему оно ошибочно.

Comment: Откуда бы не был взят текст. Ваш ответ неверен. Если желаете, то могу пояснить в чате.

Comment: Это выражение удаляет по одному символу из данного класса. Не сработает.

Comment: @Prog2010, если у вас там `amp` остается, то у вас какое-то двойное кодирование идет, так как `&amp;` это и есть `&`.